# use jsoup get comments from html and save as XML file

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jsoup

I need the help!
Go to page: http://www.tweetfeel.com/
Then type in "linkin park",Used jsoup get all user comments saved as xml?
I'm used java with netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible with jsoup, since the content is generated dynamic by javascript.